# Read form data while uploading image using .net and jquery/ajax

Tags: jquery, .net, ajax, image

I created an HttpHandler for a project I am working on. The handler receives an image from an HTML form. The data is sent via JQUERY/AJAX. I was wondering if I could receive the rest of the form data from the same call. In this example, I have two inputs: a file selector and a text box. I want to read whats in the text box also. Is it possible to retrieve the text box data when submitting to a form or do I have to do it separately?

javascript:

```
function sendFile(file) {

    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', $('#f_UploadImage')[0].files[0]);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'fileUploader.ashx',
        data: formData,
        success: function (status) {
            if (status != 'error') {
                var my_path = "MediaUploader/" + status;
                $("#myUploadedImg").attr("src", my_path);
            }
        },
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        error: function () {
            alert("Whoops something went wrong!");
        }
    });
}
```

ASP Handler code:

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.IO;
public class fileUploader : IHttpHandler {

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        try
        {
            string dirFullPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/MediaUploader/");
            string[] files;
            int numFiles;
            files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(dirFullPath);
            numFiles = files.Length;
            numFiles = numFiles + 1;
            string str_image = "";

            foreach (string s in context.Request.Files)
            {
                HttpPostedFile file = context.Request.Files[s];
                string fileName = file.FileName;
                string fileExtension = file.ContentType;

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
                {
                    fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
                    str_image = "MyPHOTO_" + numFiles.ToString() + fileExtension;
                    string pathToSave_100 = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/MediaUploader/") + str_image;
                    file.SaveAs(pathToSave_100);
                }
            }
            //  database record update logic here  ()

            context.Response.Write(str_image);
        }
        catch (Exception ac) 
        { 

        }
    }

    public bool IsReusable {
        get {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id=f_input>
<input type="file" class="upload"  id="f_UploadImage">
```

Answer (score 0):

You could grab all the form data at once and put it into your formData variable.

```
var formData = new FormData($('form')[0]);
```

Or you could append each bit of data you want separately like you have already started to do:

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', $('#f_UploadImage')[0].files[0]);
formData.append('text', $('#f_input').val());
```

Either way you should end up with all your form data getting submitted to your handler code.

Sometimes you will have to tweak the ajax settings to get images and text content to go through correctly. Below is what I am currently using to submit form data with an image and then also a token that is outside the form.

```
var formData = new FormData($('form')[0]);
formData.append("__RequestVerificationToken", $('[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val());

$.ajax({
    url: "/URL",
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    data: formData,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        //do stuff
    }
});
```